# Custom C# Enum ToString() when generated dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, enums, tostring

I generate dynamic enums that represent integer IDs from my database in a C# ASP.NET solution.  I would like two things, although neither may be possible.

1) I want the .ToString() method to give me "345" for example, not the string name of the enum (the int it represents as a string).  Every answer to this question seems to be adding

```
[Description="Blah"]
EnumName = 1
```

above the declaration and using a GetDescription() method.  I have no idea how to do this with the dynamic code that I am using.

2) I'd rather not cast to an int to use it as such, I'd rather (Enum.Name == 5) for example.  If this isn't possible I'll cast, but I really don't want to use ((int)Enum.Name)).ToString();

Here's the dynamic code generation:

```
public static void Main()
{
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

    AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("DynamicEnums");
    AssemblyBuilder ab = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);

    ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

    List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

    foreach(ReferenceType rt in GetTypes())
    {
        EnumBuilder eb = mb.DefineEnum(rt.Name, TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));

        foreach (Reference r in GetReferences(rt.ID))
        {
            eb.DefineLiteral(NameFix(r.Name), r.ID);
        }

        types.Add(eb.CreateType());
    }

    ab.Save(aName.Name + ".dll");

    foreach (Type t in types)
    {
        foreach (object o in Enum.GetValues(t))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} = {2}", t, o, ((int) o));
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        //Console.ReadKey();
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Dynamic Enums Built Successfully.");
}

public static string NameFix(string name)
{
    //Strip all non alphanumeric characters
    string r = Regex.Replace(name, @"[^\w]", "");

    //Enums cannot begin with a number
    if (Regex.IsMatch(r, @"^\d"))
        r = "N" + r;

    return r;
}
```

There may just be no way to do what I want to do, and I'll be stuck using:

```
(int)Countries.USA //For int value
((int)Countries.CAN).ToString() //For string representation of int value, ex. "354"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that must be a way to generate by reflection the Description attribute.

Comment: I don't realy see why are you using `ENUM`. Its realy usefull when you're writing some code and you can just use some value with nice name that tells you what it realy is for. Maybe its better to use some `dictionary`, since you're building it dynamicly, than `enum`?

Comment: I make the dll and then reference it in my webapps, then I bind dropdownlists / checkboxes / radiobutton lists to have values of the IDs in my database.  I want to then do things like
if (Report == Reports.SevenDay)

Comment: @Ehryk, why don't you actually declare the enums in your Code Behind, if the database schema is dynamic read them from meta data in your database?

Comment: Part of the insane design requirement is that certain administrator can add them, and I don't want a hard tie to the IDs of the database as there are multiple (dev, test, prod) that may vary in the ID.  I use this to go dynamically tie it.  Is there a better way?

Comment: P.S. A lot of these answers have been helpful, but I don't have enough reputation to vote them up, don't think I'm ungrateful.

Comment: @Ehryk I've edited my answer to give a solution using an extension method to `Enum`. Might be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you adapt the type-safe enum pattern to do what you need?

```
public class MyEnum
{
    #region Enum Values

    // Pre defined values.    
    public static readonly MyEnum ValueOne = new MyEnum(0);
    public static readonly MyEnum ValueTwo = new MyEnum(1);

    // All values in existence.
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, MyEnum> existingEnums = new Dictionary<int, MyEnum>{{ValueOne.Value, ValueOne}, {ValueTwo.Value, ValueTwo}};

    #endregion

    #region Enum Functionality

    private readonly int Value;

    private MyEnum(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static MyEnum GetEnum(int value)
    {
        // You will probably want to make this thread-safe.
        if (!existingEnums.ContainsKey(value)) existingEnums[value] = new MyEnum(value);

        return existingEnums[value];
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage:

```
private void Foo(MyEnum enumVal)
{
  return "Enum Value: " + enumVal;  // returns "Enum Value: (integer here) 
}
```

Or:

```
MyEnum.GetValue(2) == MyEnum.GetValue(4); // false
MyEnum.GetValue(3) == MyEnum.GetValue(3); // true
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this in the dynamic generation?

EnumBuilder eb = mb.DefineEnum(rt.Name, TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(MyEnum));

Comment: What do you want to do with the enum after you've created it? Compare values for different objects? You could add a GetEnumInstance(int value) method to the class above that returns the currently existing object for that value (or creates it if there is none). I will add some more code.

Comment: I think I could do something like this.  I could have a Value() and String property to get each when I wanted to.  Is there a way however to override the == to return an int or a string though? (Or even both depending on what it's being compared against?)  I'll look into this.

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx. My simple suggestion would be: `enumValue == MyEnum.GetValue(int or string here);`

Answer (score 3):

So you actually want to convert the `Enum` value to a `string` not the name? Casting to the `Enum`'s underlying type is the simplest way to get the value out. I think you will struggle to get anything shorter or simpler than `((int)...)`.

If you don't want to "enumerate" some values, or want to do somthing different you could make your own class of `YourEnum` which basically has the cast built in, casting when required seems easier and more readable.

Perhaps you actually want some constants.

```
const string Blah = "345";
```

**EDIT**

I had another idea, you could write an extension method for `Enum` like this,

```
public static class MyExtentions
{
    public static string ValueString(this Enum e)
    {
       var ut = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(e.GetType());
       var castToString = typeOf(MyExtentions).GetMethod("CastToString");
       var gcast = cast.MakeGenericMethod(ut);
       var gparams = new object[] {e};
       return gcast.Invoke(null, gparams).ToString();
    }

    public static string CastToString<T>(object o)
    {
        return ((T)o).ToString();
    }
```

}

With this you can call `ValueString()` on any `Enum` instance and get a string of the value. It clearly used reflection so the performance won't be amazing but I don't think that matters in your case.

Comment: Yes, I want the integer value as a string.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps const would be better, but I sometimes use the int and sometimes the string so I'd want int constants.  I would want Countries.USA to return 120, and Countries.USA.ToString() to be "120".  What would be the difference between Enums and named classes with const ints in them?

Comment: @Ehryk, I think my edit might actually be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using the Enum class type, how about using the Enum.Format method.

For example:

```
enum EnumClassA {One, Two, Three, Four};

...

EnumClassA chosenValue = EnumClassA.Three;

Console.WriteLine("Chosen value is {0}", Enum.Format(typeof(EnumClassA), chosenValue, "d"));
```

This should give an output of:

```
Chosen value is 2
```

**edit**

Another option would be:

```
EnumClassA.Three.ToString("d"); //Enum.Name.ToString("d")
```

This also gives a string value of "2".

** edit **

As you're doing comparisons to see if the value exists within your enums how about using Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value) which returns a bool?

```
Console.WriteLine("Does the enumClassA contain {0} result is {1}", 5, Enum.IsDefined(typeof(enumClassA), 5));
```

This gives an output of:

```
Does the enumClassA contain 5 result is False
```

Comment: I'm really looking for a more shorthand version than int casts and ToStrings, this seems a bit longer.  What I'm doing is matching to dropdownlist selected values, bound to ints, which come back as "354".

Comment: @Ehryk - To make it shorter you could create an extension Method for Enum. public static string MakeString(this Enum bla){
    return Enum.Format(bla.GetType(), bla, "d");
}

Comment: If you only want to see if the dropdownlist value esists in the enumerated type then use Enum.IsDefined - see edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

I realise that the question has been marked as answered, but perhaps using an extension might be useful?

It still allows you to use your generated enums this way.

ps.  Take care when calling GetString - don't accidentally call ToString instead!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public enum YourEnum
    {
        Apples = 1,
        Pears = 2,
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var value in (YourEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(YourEnum)))
            {
                int v = value.GetValue();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} (int)", value.ToString(), v);

                string s = value.GetString();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} (string)", value.ToString(), s);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

            //Results:

            //Apples = 1 (int)
            //Apples = 1 (string)
            //Pears = 2 (int)
            //Pears = 2 (string)
        }
    }

    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static int GetValue(this Enum value) 
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }

        public static string GetString(this Enum value)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(value).ToString();
        }
    }

}
```